# Meteor.wrapAsync not working

Tags: meteor

I was trying to get information from googlesheets using meteor. I want the call to googlesheets to be made synchronously so I googled a solution and I tried to follow the instructions listed here : https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/

I want to use the Meteor.wrapAsync because the googlesheets package I'm using did not work fine with fibers, so using futures raises an error.

This is my code (a simplified test version) :

```
fakeRead2 = function(sheetID) {
    var my_sheet = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetID);
    var syncFunc = Meteor.wrapAsync(my_sheet.useServiceAccountAuth);
    var res = syncFunc(google_service_json, function(err) {
        console.log("1");
        return "2";
    });
    console.log(res);
};
```

I expected an output of 1 and 2, but instead I got :

```
I20160421-16:55:19.535(0)? undefined
I20160421-16:55:19.873(0)? 1
```

So console.log(res); it is not called after the sync function.

I can not see why it is not called synchronously. Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to provide a `thisArg`

try changing `Meteor.wrapAsync(my_sheet.useServiceAccountAuth)` to `Meteor.wrapAsync(my_sheet.useServiceAccountAuth, my_sheet)`

Comment: Sorry, I got the same output using your suggestion.